# OpenCvSharp - Unexpected output from EstimatePoseSingleMarkers()

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, computer-vision, aruco

I am detecting a aruco marker with OpenCvSharp in this image:

[image: Image with marker]

For the first part I followed [this](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp_samples/blob/a42e483587463fc9ed3aacfb2d12e3f86063e4bc/SamplesCore/Samples/ArucoSample.cs) example which detects the marker succesfully.

```
    Mat src = new Mat("./aruco_test_4.png", ImreadModes.Color);
    Mat gray = src.CvtColor(ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);            
    var detectorParameters = DetectorParameters.Create();
    detectorParameters.CornerRefinementMethod = CornerRefineMethod.Subpix;
    detectorParameters.CornerRefinementWinSize = 9;
    var dictionary = CvAruco.GetPredefinedDictionary(PredefinedDictionaryName.Dict4X4_100);
    CvAruco.DetectMarkers(gray, dictionary, out var corners, out var ids, detectorParameters, out var rejectedPoints);
    using var detectedMarkers = src.Clone();
    CvAruco.DrawDetectedMarkers(detectedMarkers, corners, ids, Scalar.Crimson);
    detectedMarkers.SaveImage("./detectedMarkers.png");
```

Corners seem correct:

```
    [0] {(x:0.53142565 y:0.52829933)}   OpenCvSharp.Point2f
    [1] {(x:378.4717 y:0.5314254)}      OpenCvSharp.Point2f
    [2] {(x:378.46857 y:378.4717)}      OpenCvSharp.Point2f
    [3] {(x:0.52829915 y:378.46857)}    OpenCvSharp.Point2f
```

And the detectedMarkers image confirms it is found.

[image]

As the marker image is generated and unalterated I'd expect the results to be consistent and moderately obvius (as the coordinates of the detected corners are), but when using `EstimatePoseSingleMarkers()` the numbers in the resulting vector are all but consistent.

When I get the values like this:

```
    Mat rvecs = new Mat();
    Mat tvecs = new Mat();
    float markerLength = (float)0.1;
    cva.EstimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, markerLength, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);

    float rvecsVal1 = rvecs.At<float>(0, 0);
    float rvecsVal2 = rvecs.At<float>(0, 1);
    float rvecsVal3 = rvecs.At<float>(0, 2);

    float tvecsVal1 = tvecs.At<float>(0, 0);
    float tvecsVal2 = tvecs.At<float>(0, 1);
    float tvecsVal3 = tvecs.At<float>(0, 2);
```

The results are as follows:

Round 1:

```
    rvecsVal1   2               float
    rvecsVal2   0               float
    rvecsVal3   -358.89624      float

    tvecsVal1   2               float
    tvecsVal2   -5.711912E+26   float
    tvecsVal3   -5.71192657E+26 float
```

Round 2:

```
    rvecsVal1   2               float
    rvecsVal2   4.203895E-45    float
    rvecsVal3   1.55117675E+20  float

    tvecsVal1   2               float
    tvecsVal2   1.50934436E-26  float
    tvecsVal3   NaN             float
```

Round 3:

```
    rvecsVal1   2   float
    rvecsVal2   0   float
    rvecsVal3   0   float

    tvecsVal1   2   float
    tvecsVal2   0   float
    tvecsVal3   0   float
```

These are different even tho I run the application three times in a row.

When I made a homogenous transformation matrix from rvecs and tvecs and used that to transform a pointcloud (which is the ultimate goal), 2 million points turned into a line over the x axis.

```
    Mat homTransMat = Mat.Zeros(4, 4, MatType.CV_32FC1);
    //concat rotation matrix
    for (int r = 0; r < rotatMat.Rows; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < rotatMat.Cols; c++)
            homTransMat.At<float>(r, c) = tvecs.At<float>(r, c);
    //concat translation vector
    homTransMat.At<float>(0, 3) = tvecs.At<float>(0, 0);
    homTransMat.At<float>(1, 3) = tvecs.At<float>(0, 1);
    homTransMat.At<float>(2, 3) = tvecs.At<float>(0, 2);
    homTransMat.At<float>(3, 0) = homTransMat.At<float>(3, 1) = homTransMat.At<float>(3, 2) = 0;
    homTransMat.At<float>(3, 3) = 1;
    var homTransMatrix4x4Inverse = homTransMatrix4x4.Inverse();
```

Am I doing something wrong with the Aruco detection or am I misinterpreting the results? Any help would be much apreesh!

**EDIT:**
After Christoph Rackwitz pointed out that maybe I was getting garbage and I should access the data via:
`Vec3d rvecsVal = rvecs.At<Vec3d>(0);` I got consistent data.

Now I have all NAN's in rvecs and tvecs.

After changing

```
    //static Mat cameraMatrix = new(3, 3, MatType.CV_32FC1);
    //static Mat distCoeffs = new(5, 1, MatType.CV_32FC1);
    //to
    static Mat cameraMatrix = new(3, 3, MatType.CV_64FC1);
    static Mat distCoeffs = new(5, 1, MatType.CV_64FC1);
```

The NAN's disappeared, and are now consistent values:

```
    rvecsVal    {Vec3d (2.9087205410165136, 0.01423562778201259, -0.3664422237230874)}  
    tvecsVal    {Vec3d (0.023604925297790902, -0.03719938366489162, 1.332767380635899)}
```

So now I am able to generate a rotation matrix with `Cv2.Rodrigues(rvecsVal, rotatMat, jacobian);`

When I get the data from the rotation matrix like this:

```
            float[,] rotatMat_float = new float[3, 3];

            rotatMat_float[0, 0] = rotatMat.At<float>(0, 0);
            rotatMat_float[0, 1] = rotatMat.At<float>(0, 1);
            rotatMat_float[0, 2] = rotatMat.At<float>(0, 2);

            rotatMat_float[1, 0] = rotatMat.At<float>(1, 0);
            rotatMat_float[1, 1] = rotatMat.At<float>(1, 1);
            rotatMat_float[1, 2] = rotatMat.At<float>(1, 2);

            rotatMat_float[2, 0] = rotatMat.At<float>(2, 0);
            rotatMat_float[2, 1] = rotatMat.At<float>(2, 1);
            rotatMat_float[2, 2] = rotatMat.At<float>(2, 2);
```

It looks like this:

```
    [0, 0]  -3.41050484E-16 float    [0, 1] -349907.25      float    [0, 2] -1.0534988E-08  float
    [1, 0]  9.99584844E+19  float    [1, 1] -7.591237E+23   float    [1, 2] -4.19995174E+26 float
    [2, 0]  -1.10245819E-05 float    [2, 1] 8.58019E-12     float    [2, 2] 1.990967E+31    float
```

But as the Aruco marker isn't rotated in any way I'd expect a rotation matrix looking somewhat like an identity matrix, but that is not the case...

How does one debug a rotation matrix? Anyone know where this is going wrong?

Comment: arucos require some "quiet zone" around them, same as QR codes. make sure it's not sticking to a side of the picture. -- show us the values, inputs as well as outputs. show pictures. we can't run your code (even if we wanted to) because it's not a [mre].

Comment: @ Christopher, First I had the marker all the way in the upper left corner without white space and it could not find the marker as you suggest. But after moving it 1px (1, 1) this issue was resolved.

Comment: `at<T>()` it not for type conversion. OpenCV Mats encode the element type as an enum. a Mat object's type (C++ level) has no idea what's in the matrix. with `at<T>` you must use the type that corresponds to the element type of the matrix. if that is something other than `CV_32F`, but you use `at<float>`, you **will** get garbage. you can use `convertTo` to obtain a new matrix of known type, or you can check *what* the API returns, then assert that it always does return that, and then use `at<whatever>` confidently.

Comment: @ Christopher, Thank you for this insight, but I was not trying to do conversion op purpose, I was under the assumption I was dealing with a float. [OpenCvSharp](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/f41ebc05-7617-3039-76cd-67f1edf0861f.htm#:~:text=vectors%20(%40sa%20Rodrigues)-,(e.g.%20std%3A%3Avector%3Ccv%3A%3AVec3d%3E),-.%20Each%20element%20in) suggest that: ( std::vector<cv::Vec3d>) it is a vector of 3Dvector's, and so I added the leading 0 to access the 1st dimension.

Comment: I'm saying _I don't know if_ the matrix might be CV_64F instead. -- the docs on that module leave something to be desired. can you inspect the shapes (sizes) of those rvecs/tvecs matrices? can you check the type() method's return value? you should not access the matrices before you know how much data is in them. you seem to assume that there's always some data. there might not be.

Comment: rvecs.Size() yields w:1, h:1
rvecs.Size() yields CV64FC3
This I did not expect.

Comment: ah good, so it's *double float* (fp64), but **three-channel**, so it's sticking the 3D values in the channel. in numpy terms (or (N)HWC), your result has shape (N, 1, 3). so you need to access the first tvec with `at<Vec3d>(0)`, and the second (if you had one) would be `at<Vec3d>(1)`, and each Vec3d contains the xyz coordinates of the tvec. same goes for the rvecs but that's an axis-angle encoding i.e. the vector's length is the amount of rotation and its direction is the axis. -- if you don't have to use C#/C++, I wouldn't recommend it. for prototyping, Python requires a lot less B.S.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far by the way :) I feel like I'm getting closer because I'm getting consistent results, sadly `Vec3d rvecsVal = rvecs.At<Vec3d>(0, 0);` contains three NAN's, same for tvecs.
The rest of the system in written in C# so I'm hoping I can get it to work in here.

Comment: you don't have to give two dimensions to at(). for a "column vector" like here, it's fine to give just one. -- you could try getting at the bytes in the matrix... and dumping them as hex. then we could inspect those bytes and figure out what's in there.

Comment: @ Christoph, I got a little further, but still the values seem wrong, I edited the post with the progress.